# Pandas DataFrame: How to neatly select data based on value in particular column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For a DataFrame, I want to select rows based on the value of certain columns, e.g. for a data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'category': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
     'colour': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange'],
     'amount': [28.1, 5.6, 43.6, 13.3, 4.1, 27.6, 19.7, 37.5, 26.7, 73.7, 94.4, 77.5],
     'scalar': [3.4, 2.8, 3.4, 1.7, 2.2, 0.8, 1.9, 0.3, 2.4, 0.2, 0.5, 1.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The result being:

```py
   category  colour  amount  scalar
0         a     red    28.1     3.4
1         a    blue     5.6     2.8
2         a   green    43.6     3.4
3         a  orange    13.3     1.7
4         b     red     4.1     2.2
5         b    blue    27.6     0.8
6         b   green    19.7     1.9
7         b  orange    37.5     0.3
8         c     red    26.7     2.4
9         c    blue    73.7     0.2
10        c   green    94.4     0.5
11        c  orange    77.5     1.5
```

To select rows based on a `value` in a `column` I've been using `df[df[column]==value]`, e.g.:

```py
df[df['category']=='b']
  category  colour  amount  scalar
4        b     red     4.1     2.2
5        b    blue    27.6     0.8
6        b   green    19.7     1.9
7        b  orange    37.5     0.3
```

This is a really common operation in my work, so is there some kind of function that does this in a is less cluttered (especially as `column` and `value` can themselves be longer words or calculations).

I'm thinking this would be in the form `df.mask_for(column, value)` e.g.:

```py
df.mask_for('category', 'b')
  category  colour  amount  scalar
4        b     red     4.1     2.2
5        b    blue    27.6     0.8
6        b   green    19.7     1.9
7        b  orange    37.5     0.3
```

`pandas.DataFrame.where()` and `pandas.DataFrame.mask()` don't seem to achieve this.

If it's always the same column that you are referencing, you can set it as the index and use `.loc`, e.g.:

```py
df.set_index('category').loc['b',:]
          colour  amount  scalar
category                        
b            red     4.1     2.2
b           blue    27.6     0.8
b          green    19.7     1.9
b         orange    37.5     0.3
```

But if you're doing this on lots of different columns, or are using something else as the index, it seems a bit clunky to have to set/reset index all the time. Is there something similar for the general case?

Thanks!

Comment: check out the pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: With the given code, the dataframe is not indexed by `category` and `colour` while your print output suggests otherwise.

Comment: @QuangHoang, thanks for pointing it out, I had used that from a previous post. Updated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the query function as an alternative.

```
df.query('"category" == "b"')
```

You could also write your own function, so that you can save yourself keystrokes later.

```
def mask_for(df,column,value):
    return(df.loc[df[column]==value])

mask_for(df,'category','b')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I think the own-function route might be the best!

Answer (score 3):

`df.query()` does what you ask for , just want to post another method if you want to query like you would in sql:

```
import pandasql as ps
query="select * from df where category='a' and amount > 20"
ps.sqldf(query)
```

---

**Output**

```
  category colour  amount  scalar
0        a    red    28.1     3.4
1        a  green    43.6     3.4
```